# How to add a "not" action in cmd complex lines

Tags: python, command-prompt

I have made a program with which I download all my songs as mp3, however, unless I use the default name, it doesnt get saved as "song.mp3" but rather "song". Someone online suggested this :

`for /R %x in (*) do ren "%x" *.mp3`

But this also replaces the program's extension. converter.py now reads as converter.mp3

To make this easier and not have to rename the files all at once, I thought I would integrate this into the code by using the os module. But then the code wouldn't run the next time.

Is there a way to add a 'not' operator or something of the like so that the code replaces all extensions with '.mp3' **except** '.py'

What I have currently added to the program :

`os.system('for /R %x in (*) do ren "%x" *.mp3')`

`os.system('ren converter.mp3 converter.py')`

Comment: This is a python program calling `os.system` to run a shell command? Just use python.

Comment: I was using a shell command at first outside the program. Decided to integrate it into the program itself instead of running it every few downloads. Will search up on how to use python for the renaming

Answer (score 2):

I feel like this would be easier to fix at download time rather than afterwards... but

```
for item in os.listdir():
   if os.path.isfile(item) and not item.endswith('.py'):
      os.rename(item, item + '.mp3')
```

Comment: You might want to make that `item.split('.')[-1]` to take the final component. As stands, you'll fail on names with extra periods like `my.song.mp3`. Better, use glob or pathlib.

Comment: Ye, I realized that issue and was thinking up a fix, I think my new way should work fine in this case~ glob/pathlib would be safest though.

Comment: I think this should work. I don't have any files with a double full-stop since they don't have any extension at all. Thanks!